# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected main_input to have shape (2491,) but got array with shape (1016,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

```
res = data['text_long'].str.split().str.len().max()
print('The maximum number of words in the document are:',res)#1016
print('The maximum number of documents in the datafame are:',len(data))#2491
DOC_LEN = 2491
MAX_WORDS = 1016

tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data["text_long"]
df = pad_sequences(sequences,maxlen=MAX_WORDS,padding='post',truncating='post')
X= df
y=data['worry_level']
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
#Splitting for training and testing dataset
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
#Splitting for validation and training dataset
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)


    from keras.layers import Embedding, Dense, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, \
Dropout, Activation, Input, Flatten, Concatenate
from keras.models import Model
EMBEDDING_DIM=100
main_input = Input(shape=(DOC_LEN,), dtype='int32', name='main_input')

embed_1 = Embedding(input_dim = MAX_WORDS, \
                    output_dim = EMBEDDING_DIM, \
                    input_length = DOC_LEN,\
                    name='embedding')(main_input)
conv1d_1= Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, \
                 name='conv_unigram',\
                 activation='relu')(embed_1)
pool_1 = MaxPooling1D(DOC_LEN-1+1, \
                      name='pool_unigram')(conv1d_1)
flat_1 = Flatten(name='flat_unigram')(pool_1)

conv1d_2= Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, \
                 name='conv_bigram',\
                 activation='relu')(embed_1)
pool_2 = MaxPooling1D(DOC_LEN-2+1, name='pool_bigram')(conv1d_2)
flat_2 = Flatten(name='flat_bigram')(pool_2)

conv1d_3= Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, \
                 name='conv_trigram',activation='relu')(embed_1)
pool_3 = MaxPooling1D(DOC_LEN-3+1, name='pool_trigram')(conv1d_3)
flat_3 = Flatten(name='flat_trigram')(pool_3)

z=Concatenate(name='concate')([flat_1, flat_2,flat_3])

drop_1=Dropout(rate=0.5, name='dropout')(z)

# Create the output layer
preds = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='output')(drop_1)

modelb = Model(inputs=main_input, outputs=preds)

modelb.summary()

modelb.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = modelb.fit(X_train,
                    y_train,
                    epochs=20,
                    batch_size=128,



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-164-8ad2062df35f> in <module>
      3                     epochs=20,
      4                     batch_size=128,
----> 5                     validation_data=(X_val, y_val))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
   1152             sample_weight=sample_weight,
   1153             class_weight=class_weight,
-> 1154             batch_size=batch_size)
   1155 
   1156         # Prepare validation data.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    577             feed_input_shapes,
    578             check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 579             exception_prefix='input')
    580 
    581         if y is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    143                             ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have shape ' +
    144                             str(shape) + ' but got array with shape ' +
--> 145                             str(data_shape))
    146     return data
    147 

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected main_input to have shape (2491,) but got array with shape (1016,)
                        validation_data=(X_val, y_val))
```

##I am trying to classify a worry level which is 0 or 1 and it depends on the text data of reviews. I am just trying to take the maximum words of a row and padded all the row with that equal length. I am trying to take all the rows which is 2491, whereas the max words are same post truncation. However, I am running into fitting the shape issues. Essentially, I am having 2491 rows or documents and 1016 columns or sequence of words converted to indices. Please let me know where I can fix my code to fit the model. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the shape of your data. It should be (1016, 2491).

I think your shape is (2491, 1016).

If so - you should transpose it.